# Unix - bash -OSX

Tags: macos, bash, unix, grep

Trying to use grep to find some information. Evaluate the information. Then perform a  function.

Heres what I have, any help is appreciated.

FIXED TO:

```
#! /bin/bash

UT=$(/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType | grep "Time since boot" | grep "days")

if [ "$UT" -ge "5 days" ]; then
echo this
else    
echo that
fi
```

SPSoftwareDataType looks like this:
    System Software Overview:

```
  System Version: OS X 10.9.5 
  Kernel Version: Darwin 13.4.0
  Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
  Boot Mode: Normal
  Computer Name: xxxxxxxxxxxx
  User Name: xxxxxxxxxx (xxxxxxxxxx)
  Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
  Time since boot: 8 days 3:25
```

Trying using sysctl

```
#! /bin/bash

UT=$(awk -F":" ' $4 > 200 ' sysctl -n kern.boottime)

echo $UT
if [ “$UT” -ge “1430315296” ]; then
    echo this
else    
    echo that
fi
```

Comment: What's the problem? (Aside from non-ASCII quotation marks.)

Comment: Also use `-ge` instead of `>=`

Comment: Here is what is returning: grep: since: No such file or directory
grep: boot”: No such file or directory line 5: [: “??: integer expression expected
that         I think because it is returning then just a number, such as: 8 days 3:25

Comment: And better to not use old back-tics. Use parentheses like this  `US=$(/user/sbin....."days")`. Not like this `echo =“this”` but this: `echo ="this"`

Comment: And could you post some of the `SPSoftwareDataType` file?

Comment: System Software Overview:

      System Version: OS X 10.9.5
      Kernel Version: Darwin 13.4.0
      Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: XXXXXXXXX
      User Name: XXXXXXX (XXXXXX)
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
      Time since boot: 8 days 3:25

Comment: Edit you post and add data there to get correct formatting.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see how you expect `awk` to compare anything specified in days and hours with anything else... nor do I know why you would choose to parse `system_profiler` output.

Have you considered:

```
sysctl -n kern.boottime
{ sec = 1431023230, usec = 0 } Thu May  7 19:27:10 201
```

which will give the boot time in seconds since the epoch which is just a simple integer you can compare with other times?

So, you can parse out the seconds like this

```
UT=$(sysctl -n kern.boottime | awk -F"[ ,]+" '{print $4}')
```

the `-F"[ ,]+"` says to treat multiple spaces or commas as field separators.

Comment: yes I think you are right on.  Thanks, I am goint to work with this and see if I can figure it out.  Thanks for setting me on the right track!

Comment: I am getting somewhere but, I cant get awk to compare to the commands parse. If you can take a look and see where im going wrong... Thanks I posted it above

Comment: I have updated the answer with a way to parse it out.

Comment: Thanks Mark that works great!  Wish I had enough Rep to vote for it. Another question: My Secs appear to stay at a static number? is there a time frame for them to update, or a way of manually forcing an update?

Comment: The `secs` is the seconds elapsed since 1st Jan 1970 at which the machine started - it is fixed at the time it boots and doesn't change.

Comment: wow, well that is going to add another variable....  any idea how to get the current secs, i.e.  x=date +%s     1-1-1970 - x

Comment: Like this `date +'%s'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do all in `awk`

```
awk '/Time since boot.*days/ {print ($4>5?"This":"That")}' file
This
```

```
awk '/Time since boot.*days/ {print ($4>8?"This":"That")}' file
That
```

Edit:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType | awk '/Time since boot.*days/ {print ($4>8?"This":"That")}'
```

Comment: tried this: #! /bin/bash

awk '/Time since boot.*days/ {print ($4>5?"This":"That")}' /usr/sbin/system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType                                                      but getting the  error awk: can't open file SPSoftwareDataType
 input record number 78, file SPSoftwareDataType
 source line number 1

Comment: Try to run the `awk` from the command line, not in bash script. Just type: `/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType | awk '/Time since boot.*days/ {print ($4>8?"This":"That")}'`